# How can i assign a string array item to edittext in the other class so when when in user mode user changes edittext , item changes also?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, auto-update

How can i assign a string array item to edittext in the other class so when when in user mode user changes edittext , item changes also ? I have this code, and as a consequence i get item in a form of default edittext string(designer mode). I want from it to change at the same time user change edittext. Plese Help.
'private void kidaj() {

```
        LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        View regisText = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_moj_recept1, null);
        EditText user = (EditText) regisText.findViewById(R.id.seees);
        String usr = user.getText().toString();
        recepies[0]=usr;
```

AND THIS IS OTHER CLASS

```
private final static String STORETEXT ="storetext.txt";
private final static String STORETEXT1="storetext1.txt";
private final static String STORETEXT2="storetext2.txt";


private EditText txtEditor;
private EditText txtEditor1;
private EditText txtEditor2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moj_recept1);
    txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.seees);
    txtEditor1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.seees1);
    txtEditor2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.seees2);
    readFileInEditor();
    readFileInEditor1();
    readFileInEditor2();

}
public void saveClicked(View v) {

    try {

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));

        out.write(txtEditor.getText().toString());
        out.close();

        OutputStreamWriter out1=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT1, 0));

        out1.write(txtEditor1.getText().toString());
        out1.close();

        OutputStreamWriter out2=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT2, 0));

        out2.write(txtEditor2.getText().toString());
        out2.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "RECEPT JE SAČUVAN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
public void readFileInEditor()

{

    try {

        InputStream in = openFileInput(STORETEXT);

        if (in != null) {

            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);

            String str;

            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buf.append(str );

            }

            in.close();

            txtEditor.setText(buf.toString());

        }

    }

    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

    }

    catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
public void readFileInEditor1()

{

    try {

        InputStream in1 = openFileInput(STORETEXT1);

        if (in1 != null) {

            InputStreamReader tmp1 = new InputStreamReader(in1);

            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(tmp1);

            String str1;

            StringBuilder buf1 = new StringBuilder();

            while ((str1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {

                buf1.append(str1);

            }

            in1.close();

            txtEditor1.setText(buf1.toString());

        }

    }

    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

    }

    catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
public void readFileInEditor2()

{

    try {

        InputStream in2 = openFileInput(STORETEXT2);

        if (in2 != null) {

            InputStreamReader tmp2 = new InputStreamReader(in2);

            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(tmp2);

            String str2;

            StringBuilder buf2 = new StringBuilder();

            while ((str2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {

                buf2.append(str2);

            }

            in2.close();

            txtEditor2.setText(buf2.toString());

        }

    }

    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {

    }

    catch (Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If I am not getting wrong, you want to add a textChangedListener for changing item values as user changes values in EditText.

You can use TextChangedListener here:

```
EditText myEditTextField = new EditText(this);

myEditTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

You can perform tasks according to your need. It has 3 methods:

1.beforeTextChanged

2.onTextChanged

3.afterTextChanged

So you can make a temporary variable and as the text changes, save the values in it and whenever you want to change the variable values, give a command in the method,and  It will perform your task.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i've tried this but  my try wasn't succesful , maybe that is not solution or maybe i didn't tried it properly. Anyway Thanks very much for reply

Comment: It should have solved your problem(I thought). I am sorry if it didn't, and your welcome sir :) @MilošVukadinović

Comment: Ok, i realised i have to assign recepies[0] to that storetext.txt in other class can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? @MilošVukadinović
If yes and my answer helped you then you can mark it as accepted, so that others can also get help from answer